# jquery/javascript: How do I remove the 'active' class from all the children of a parent element?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, html-lists

I have a few lists, something like so:

```
<div id="menu" class="divclass">
    <ul id="firstlist">
        <li><a href='#'>...</a></li>
        <li><a href='#'>...</a></li>
        <li><a href='#'>...</a></li>
    </ul>
    <ul id="secondlist">
        <li><a href='#'>...</a></li>
        <li><a href='#'>...</a></li>
        <li><a href='#'>...</a></li>
    </ul>
    <!-- etc. - similar unordered lists follow. -->
</div>
```

When one of the `<a>` elements is clicked, I want to clear all the `<li>` elements of its list of the `'active'` class. I've been fiddling around with `.parent()`, `.children()`, and `.removeClass('active')` but I think I'm totally missing something because I can't get it to work. Can anyone give me a hand? This is the beginning of the script:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(".divclass ul li a").click(function() { ... }}
```

where `.divclass` is the class of the div that contains the unordered lists.

Comment: .divclass does not exist in the HTML you gave

Comment: good point, I'll fix that.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Remove all

```
$(".divclass ul li a").click(function() {
    $(this).closest('.divclass').find('li').removeClass('active');
}};
```

Remove only form the same list

```
$(".divclass ul li a").click(function() {
    $(this).closest('ul').find('li').removeClass('active');
}};
```

If you also want to add the class active to the li parent of the a clicked:

```
$(".divclass ul li a").click(function() {
    $(this).parent().addClass('active').siblings().removeClass('active');
}};
```

Comment: Thanks for that edit too - that's tidier than what I had for adding the active class.

Answer (score 2):

You can use:

```
 $("#menu a").click(function() {
    //to remove class active from li elements
    $(this).closest('ul').find('.active').removeClass('active');


    //to remove li with active class
    $(this).closest('ul').find('.active').remove();
 });
```